# Splitting Unconventional csv file into multiple csv's

Tags: python, csv, export

I'm currently working with a dataset that needs to be split into multiple files. The data is currently structured in the following format:

Data Structure:

[image: Data Structure]

Reading the data utilizing pandas isn't an option given the unconventional formatting and I'm not too familiar with the python csv module.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: The `csv` module will read it without error if you can export it as CSV (the image looks like an Excel spreadsheet), `list(csv.reader(csvfile))`. You'll get something like `[['engine type','engine info'],[],['temp','pressure'],['x','y'],['x','y'],['x','y'],[],[],['engine type','engine info'], ...]`. Then you can segment the data into a format you can use.

Comment: You'll probably get better answers if you provide sample input as text rather than an image.

Answer (score 0):

1. Excel save to csv
2. read file w/ `open('file.csv')`
3. split the file content w/ `str.split`
4. use `io` and `csv.reader`

```py
import csv
import io
content = 'aaaa,222\n22,33'
f = io.StringIO(content)
r = csv.reader(f)
for row in r:
    print(row)
# ['aaaa', '222']
# ['22', '33']
```